# How to transfer data from one app to another app from different iOS devices which have same WiFi network in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to transfer data from one app to another app from different iOS devices which have same WiFi network

Comment: You mean to say sharing file, video or any kind of data to each other devices?

Comment: @RushabhShah yes.. For example on device 1 - Screen 1 - I change in my textfield "2" to "3" And i want to send that to another device in another app to update data there that i changed "2" to "3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used MultipeerConnectivity framework and it works great

Comment: I refer this one.. https://www.toptal.com/ios/collusion-ios-multipeerconnectivity

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement **Client/Server** model for this in which if you want to transfer file from 1 device you need to make it server and make it discoverable on the go thourgh LAN/WIFI scanner libraries and then implement **FTP/SMB** protocols to transfer files. On the other side make the second device Client which will then discover devices on the same network and allow them to connect through the implemented protocols.

Answer (score 0):

What task do you want to solve? Maybe **MultipeerConnectivity** framework will be appropriate in your case. It doesn't need event same wifi network